# Pcap bytestring types

Tags: haskell

So I am trying to use pipes and Network.Pcap together but I am running into a bug with Data.ByteString types and Network.Pcap bytestring types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Network.Pcap
import Pipes 

import Data.ByteString
--import Data.ByteString.Lazy

getPacket :: (MonadIO m) => PcapHandle -> Producer' (PktHdr, ByteString) m ()
getPacket handle = do
    x <- liftIO $ nextBS handle   
    yield x

main = return ()
```

As you can see from the comment it isnt a problem of if the bytestring is lazy or strict because i tried both. This is the error:

```
PCAP.hs:12:15:
Couldn't match type `bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString'
              with `ByteString'
Expected type: (PktHdr, ByteString)
  Actual type: (PktHdr,
                bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString)
In the first argument of `yield', namely `x'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: yield x
In the expression:
  do { x <- liftIO $ nextBS handle;
       yield x }
```

What is wrong with my bytestring types?

Comment: I think you are getting interference from an undesired installation of `bytestring`. You should unregister any bytestring version that didn't come with your ghc. `ghc-pkg list bytestring` will show the trouble ... or, in a sandbox, `cabal sandbox hc-pkg list bytestring`. Either way, the second, local bytestring has to go.

Comment: Look at the first stanza from `ghc-pkg list`, the globally installed packages. You will generally not want `cabal install` installing new versions of these unless you know what you are doing (in fact for several packages this is no problem, but bytestring is pretty fundamental). If any of these gives you trouble you can add a line like `constraint: bytestring installed` or `constraint: transformers installed` etc. to your `~/.cabal/config`

Comment: if I unregister the packages it would break dependiences

Comment: Kyle McKean, yes, they are the ones that got the rogue bytestring installed. I think you should unregister them too, and start over with the `constraint: bytestring installed` bit. Are you using ghc >= 7.8 ?

Answer (score 1):

As @Michael said, you appear to have two versions of the `bytestring` package installed. This is apparent from the error, any time you see a package version in the type error (`bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString`) it is a good bet.

So, use sandboxes to avoid this issue in normal workflow (when possible) and unregister (`ghc-pkg unregister bytestring-something-something`, based on `ghc-pkg list`) one of the bytestring packages then re-install anything that was depending on the excess package.

Comment: /var/lib/ghc/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.0.2
/home/kyle/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
   bytestring-0.10.6.0

Comment: which one should i unregister??

Comment: Personally?  I'm not afraid of breakage so I unregister the older package and re-build any deps on the newer one.  Also, some of my packages don't work with version `0.10.0.2` so I really _have_ to use a newer one.

Comment: @KyleMcKean You should unregister the one you installed (0.10.6.0) and leave the one that came with GHC, since ghc-the-library depends on it. If you really need a newer bytestring, consider upgrading GHC.

Comment: Yes, I see it must be a pretty old ghc, since ghc-7.8.3 had a higher bytestring number. See here https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_8_4 and follow the instructions ... basically `configure --prefix=$HOME/myghc && make install`, aligning paths in the obvious way. Your existing cabal will still work, but can get a new one with cabal install. Here are somewhat fancier instructions https://github.com/yantonov/install-ghc/blob/master/ubuntu/install-ghc-ubuntu.md there are many like it.